# error:function definition does not declare parameters in setter

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple c++ program and it gave me error in the setter, function definition does not declare parameters, although there was a setter above it and it worked correctly the error is in the function named setattack here is the code:
{

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Warrior{
private:
string name;
int attack;
int defense;
public:
void setname(string m){
name=m;
}
string getname(){
return name;}

void setattack{int aw}{
attack=aw;
}
int getattack(){
return attack;}

void setdefense{int dw}{
defenset=dw;
}
int getdefense(){
return defense;}


void kill(const Monster &monster){

}


};

int main()
{


return 0;
}


}
```

Comment: Replace `void setattack{int aw`} by `void setattack(int aw)` . Same with `void setdefense{int dw}` to `void setdefense(int dw)`

Comment: You should be using parenthesis when calling or defining a function

Comment: thank you i didn't notice it

Comment: also some typos. defenset=dw; should be defense=dw

Comment: i edited it and the program run correctly thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your set function you have used {} curly braces for arguments I think it should be (), and there is an extra } after main.